# Words for diagonal directions

Tags: terminology, mathematics

I'm a mathematician currently working on a problem involving splitting a square into two triangles, either by a line connecting top-left and bottom-right, or top-right and bottom left.  I'm trying to think of natural names for these, but the only thing I could think of was *acute* and *grave* (after the directions of accents, originally Greek I believe).  Are there other options?

Comment: If you are looking to simply identify them in text, you could refer to the forward slash(/) and the back slash (\\), but note that many people don’t intuitively grasp which is which.

Comment: I thought about forward/backslash and can see disadvantages: they're rather informal, have common usage in computing (path separators) but the target audience would not necessarily be computer literate ... solidus and reverse-solidus are a bit more formal, but have an asymmetry I'd prefer to avoid (not just in form, the reverse-solidus dates from the 60s I believe, and was also constructed for computing application).

Comment: NW - SE and SW - NE seem fairly clear.

Comment: Duplicate of [Terminology for diagonal line that also indicates orientation](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/250929/191178), but the answers there aren't so great.

Comment: The heraldic terms for those lines are [_bend_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bend_(heraldry))  (for the top left to bottom right, as seen full-on), and the _bend sinister_ in the opposite orientation. As the shield was worn, the bend went from the holder's right shoulder to his left hip.

Comment: Probably the most common way to do this is to use a clockface reference, with 2-to-8 and 10-to-4 as the diagonals. This is used across a wide range of disciplines.

Comment: There is also "up to right" and "up to left." Do you  have a sample sentence with an underline so we know what to put in it?

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective? Please create an example sentence with a fill-in-the-blank ____ where these words would appear. For example: *Draw a ____ line to divide the square.*

Comment: I wouldn't use "acute", because "acute triangle" is a specific term in geometry. It might cause some confusion.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to provide commentary. The correct place for that is as a comment on the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for the interesting replies and discussion. I think I'll go for positive/negative since for the target numerate audience, the notation is extremely easy to describe and remember: "we discuss the division of squares into triangles via their diagonals; positive or negative according to their gradient". Forward/backward tilting, bending do assume a left-right orthography, likewise upward/downward which also suggest a direction of travel along the diagonal (upward is bottom left to top right), while my intent is to identify lines rather than vectors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have seen them being referred to as **positive** diagonal (forward slash, / ) and **negative** diagonal (backslash, \ ), basically in reference to their slope as seen in a standard euclidean axial system.

In a mathematical setting, I feel those terms might be more intuitive than names of accents most speakers of English are not directly familiar with.

As mentioned in a comment, I probably picked up this usage from sodoku.
It is used regularly on the [cracking the cryptic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h54qbSfGG7U#t=2m28s) Youtube channel.
[Logic masters Germany](https://logic-masters.de/Raetselportal/Raetsel/zeigen.php?chlang=en&id=0008LL) uses this terminology as well:

> Digits cannot repeat along the positive diagonal.

Comment: Without supporting references, this comes across as anecdotal or at best niche usage.  The string 'positive diagonal' seems to appear most often when discussing matrices, and refers to the values of elements, not orientation.

Comment: The terms "positive diagonal" and "negative diagonal" are used in this way in sudoku, for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h54qbSfGG7U#t=2m28s) Simon, in explaining a rule, uses these terms.

Comment: For matrices, the NW-SE diagonal is the _main_ or _principal_ diagonal, the NE-SW the _minor_ or _anti-_ diagonal (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227345/), so in a sense contrary the positive/negative

Comment: Ah, another CTC devotee.

Comment: @PhilSweet Yup, I need the daily double dose :)

Answer (score 9):

One idea is to call them according to their attitude from left to right, that is, an ***inclining* diagonal** when going from bottom to top and a ***declining* diagonal** when going from top to bottom.

For example, these quilting directions by Linda Ambrosini (["Pixie Sticks," Hoffman Fabrics](https://hoffmancaliforniafabrics.net/patterns/files/Pixie-Sticks-pattern_web.pdf)) make use of the *inclining cut* and *inclining diagonal* to describe a cut going from bottom left to top right and the *declining cut* and diagonal for the other case. Then an explanation of *[Hanidoku](https://www.sudopedia.org/wiki/Hanidoku)*, a hexagonal Sudoku variant, uses *inclining diagonal* and *descending diagonal* to describe lines of hexagons.

You could also use **rising** and **falling diagonal**, which are the names of the Unicode characters ⟋ and ⟍, respectively ([Compart 1](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+27CB), [2](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+27CD)). In both cases, you rely on an English reader's tendency to read from left to right and thus to perceive a line as rising or falling based on its behavior going from left to right.

Comment: "Rising" and "falling" seem intuitive, based on the shape of line graphs and similar. "Inclining" and "declining" less so, as "[incline](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incline)" typically means to lean or tilt regardless of direction, and can mean to bow down.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit off the wall, but could you possibly rotate your problem to dividing a diamond into two triangles? Then you can refer to the lines as vertical and horizontal, and avoid any confusion.

Comment: That's very true! (and out of the box thinking), but rather putting the cart before the horse :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given the standard (and very widespread) road signs for hills such as that below *which is for an uphill gradient*.

[image: Ascending Gradient Road Sign]

I would suggest that either Ascending/Descending or Up/down slant.

Of course in a formal paper you could always mention, or illustrate, the words that you decide to use either in an introductory section or at the first usage.